# How safe is it to run Windows Server 2008 R2 datacenter without SP1?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vps, hosting, windows-update

I manage a Windows VPS on hosteurope.de. I've been trying to update it to SP1 - it says Windows Update are disable by group policy, and workarounds found online don't seem to work - same thing for downloading and attempting the install of the offline SP1 installer.

It seems that (just discovered), "No Microsoft updates, including service packs, can be installed inside containers" and this is a limitation of the Parallels software.
source: http://kb.parallels.com/en/11153

The OS interface was originally in German and "Not all Windows 2008 R2 SP1 editions and locales are supported by Parallels Virtuozzo Containers for Windows" - that may be the reason why SP1 was not applied yet.

So it seems the window install is not up-to-date, and it is being used for hosting several websites, in their public/production form.

How unsafe and acceptable is this practice, in this particular context?

PS: Updates and fixes released by Microsoft are (seemingly) regularly applied - so it's only a matter of SP1 not being applied.

Comment: How unsafe and acceptable was it before SP1 was released? That's how safe and acceptable it is.

Comment: @joeqwerty I would say that it's worse than that, because many of the vulnerabilities that were fixed by SP1 were not known to the public before SP1 came out. Now those vulnerabilities are more widely known and so more likely to be targeted than they were pre-SP1.

Comment: Time to stop using Virtuozzo.

Comment: @joequerty, not really, because a discovered and known vulnerability, and a yet to be discovered vulnerability are not the same. Once a vulnerability is discovered, you will have many persons trying to take advantage of it and scanning other computers for vulnerabilities and that surely greatly multiplies the risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to quantify how unsafe it is to run an operating system that does not have the latest patches and fixes. But we can agree that it's best practice to stay current on your patches as much as possible.

Software vendors release patches to remediate security vulnerabilities, compatibility issues, performance problems, etc. They don't just release patches for no reason. So naturally it should always be desirable to keep your OS patches up to date. Not doing so is a risk.

Companies with serious IT operations have structured, planned patch rollout cycles, and testing and staging environments that get hit with patches and updates first to ensure that there are no unforeseen problems before they get rolled to production.

I suppose if you did still want to try to quantify the risk, you'd need to look up the documentation for every patch that you're missing, and every bug and vulnerability you find in that list, you can say "Yep, my operating system has that bug, and that bug, and that bug."

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't help me tremendously towards my decision (I'm not going to read the changelog for each fix - I'm only managing one server with a handful of websites), but it might very well be the best answer that I'll get, and every bit of knowledge and every sincere answer is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry... I personally wouldn't do business with a provider that can't offer me an up-to-date OS.

Comment: Well I went into "installed updates" and it seems that fixes and updates are regularly applied up to the present, the last update being applied on 4/4 (KB2809289) handling vulnerabilities which seem to be less than one month old.
So this is an issue of only SP1 not being installed - now I'm even more confused. Otherwise, I'd agree with you.